# Edit a table in database from jsp page

Tags: jsp

I have made a `editbooks.jsp` page .The problem is it is redirecting me to `admin.jsp` page without updating the table.

More clearly `editbooks.jsp` is not working.

I code looks fine but I could not relocate what the problem is.

```
//editbooks.jsp

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import='java.io.*,java.sql.*' %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="editbooks.jsp">
<%
  if(request.getParameter("add")!=null)
   {
    try
    {
        String id=request.getParameter("id");

        String bname=request.getParameter("bname");
        String author=request.getParameter("author");
        String pub=request.getParameter("pub");
        String price=request.getParameter("price");
        String cat=request.getParameter("cat");
        String qty=request.getParameter("qty");
        String pic=request.getParameter("pic");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookstore?user=root&password=admin");

        String update="update books set bname=?,author=?,pub=?,price=?,cat=?,qty=?,pic=? where bid=?";

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(update);
        ps.setString(1, bname);
        ps.setString(2, author);
        ps.setString(3, pub);
        ps.setString(4, price);
        ps.setString(5, cat);
        ps.setString(6, qty);
        ps.setString(7, pic);
        ps.setString(8, id);

        ps.executeUpdate();

        response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
     }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
%>
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>Book Name:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bname" id="bname"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Author:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Publication:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pub" id="pub"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Price:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="price" id="price"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Category:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cat" id="cat"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Quantity:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Screenshot:</label></td>
<td><input type="file" name="pic" id="pic"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Update"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have another page "admin.jsp" where i am sending the value id

```
<td><a href="editbooks.jsp?id=<%= id %>">Edit</a></td>
```

when I click on Edit ,I get the editbooks.jsp page with correct id displaying on the url
for example:`http://localhost:8082/bookstore/editbooks.jsp?id=4`

but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your updating your db with `where bid=?` which you obtain from request parameter:

```
String id=request.getParameter("id");
```

But you are not sending any parameter with the name "id". Thus sql statement is not satisfied and no record was updated.

I think you would have stored your id in `request scope`. If yes, then you should use a hidden field to store the value inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}" />
```

**Update**

if you are sendng it as parameter to `edit.jsp`, you need to assign it to a hidden field to store the value inside your form as well. then **only** it will be passed as parameter to the next page:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${param['id']}" />
```

Comment: I had a parameter 'id' passed from admin.jsp page to editbooks.jsp page.Please help to find the problem.

Comment: See my update, you can get your param using ${param['id']}. This should work